# Linker settings

Tags: c++, python, boost, linker, cmake

I'm trying to link boost.python with my application in cmake build-system.
The most important parts in my **CMakeList.txt**:

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system date_time python REQUIRED)

add_definitions(-Wall -g -msse2 -fPIC)
```

And, of course, including/linking boost's and python's libraries/headers.

Now this fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: libboost_python.a(from_python.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
libboost_python.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
```

I decided to go to the cmake temporary build folder and find generated **object file (*.o)**.
I've applied command for it:

```
g++ -shared FILE.cpp.o -L/usr/lib -lboost_python -o MyModule.so
```

As a result I got workable MyModule module for python! So, lets look at cmake linker string and find the difference. I ran make with **VERBOSE=1**:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC -g  -shared -Wl,-soname,libScript.so -o ../../lib/libScript.so CMakeFiles/LogManagerWrapper.cpp.o -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_python -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpython2.7
```

During excluding some parts of  the linker flags I found that my problem is in **-Wl,-Bstatic** before boosts' libraries list.

I wonder from where that argument came because I noticed **Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF** in CMakeList.txt.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not show the code that uses the Boost libraries, so I assume it's just:

```
target_link_libraries(foo ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Could you please add

```
message("XXX ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

around that point? I suspect that will print a list of libraries with .a extension, which CMake then converts into that `-Wl,-Bstatic -lxxx`. Examine the path where .a libraries are located and check if there are .so counterparts. My guess is that you actually have only static libraries built.

Comment: I checked it. There are both: a and so.